# Retrieve WebUrls of Recent Files in OneDrive

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the following Graph API call to retrieve my recent files from OneDrive for Business;

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent
```

In the response, the `driveitem` objects are more sparse than the schema suggests;

[image: screenshot of JSON OneDrive response]

Specifically, it's missing the `webUrl` property.

If I try to explicitly request that property as follows;

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent?select=webUrl
```

Then I just get the following response;

```
{  
   "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
   "value":[  
      {  
         "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem"
      },
      {  
         "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem"
      },
      {  
         "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem"
      },
      {  
         "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem"
      },
      {  
         "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I get this data from the Graph API? I've tried making subsequent calls to get the item(s) directly using this call (as per the [documentation](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/drive_recent));

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<remoteItem.driveId>/items/<id>`

However, this always seems to just fail with;

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "itemNotFound",
    "message": "The resource could not be found.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "a86bdc25-771b-4b90-9c17-942e05bd9ed3",
      "date": "2016-05-22T08:21:57"
    }
  }
}
```

With regards to the Azure Active Directory permissions, I have a Native Client application registered and I've given it **all** Microsoft Graph API delegated permissions possible (all 40 of them). Overkill I know, but I just want to get this working first then will remove permissions piecemeal until I've just got the necessary ones left.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "Files.Read.All", "Sites.Read.All" scopes, you can find it in azure portal, "Read all files that user can access".

[image]

With that, the bearer token translates to
[image]

Without which, the bearer token translates to
[image]

I'm having the same "itemNotFound" error with "Read all files that user can access" being unchecked, but success with that checked.